# How to get the value of textfield using jquery and assign it to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple web page which takes the value from the input box and passes it to the next page or form. Only problem is I don't know how to use `jquery` to get the value and assign it as a `php` value. I want to pass this value in into the `URL`

This is my code:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php
    print
        "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='usr'>".
        "<a href='calculate.php?id={45}&tt='><button class='btn btn-success'>Calculate</button></a>";

?>
```

How do I pass the result value to `"<a href='calculate.php?id={45}&tt='>`, where `tt` is the value of the box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function to get the value and change the button to use that function:

So your final php code would be:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
    function calculate() {
        var tt = $("#usr").val();
        location.href = "calculate.php?id={45}&tt=" + tt;
    }
</script>

<input type='text' class='form-control' id='usr'>
<button class='btn btn-success' onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

I removed the `<php? print...` because it's just plain html.

Comment: Does that go out of the php stuff? Sorry, but could you kindly put this in my original code please? It makes it easier for me to understand

Comment: Thanks, but how do you do it if it is a php file? I need it in a php file as I intend on adding more to it

Comment: Please, it will really help me a lot

Comment: @BenjMikesozery just paste the code in the php file without the <php?.. etc and that will work

Comment: but then it wont be a php file

Comment: isnt there a way to just include the php stuff?

Comment: @BenjMikesozery yes it will, just try it.

Comment: it doesnt work. i really need it with the print stuff

Comment: thats why i was struggling

Comment: also why cant i see the url when i submit, arent i meant to see the value in the url

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery is very simple for such scenario.

```
<?php
print
    "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='usr'>".
    "<a id='button' href='#'><button class='btn btn-success'>Calculate</button></a>";

?>
```

Here I have added id attribute to your anchor tag or link whatever you call it.

Now the jquery part:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var usr = $("#usr").val();
        $("#button").attr("href","calculate.php?id={45}&tt="+usr);
    });
</script>
```

Or If you want the url to be changed when the value of that particular text field changes then you may try following.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#usr").change(function(){
            var usr = $("#usr").val();
            $("#button").attr("href","calculate.php?id={45}&tt="+usr);
        });            
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps. If you want to learn more about jquery change event then you can have a look at [jQuery Change Event](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

********** Editing from here ************

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Whatever your title is</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    print
        "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='usr'>".
        "<a id='button' href='#'><button class='btn btn-success'>Calculate</button></a>";

    ?>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#usr").change(function(){
                var usr = $("#usr").val();
                $("#button").attr("href","calculate.php?id={45}&tt="+usr);
            });            
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the whole file will look like bellow

Comment: Thanks, so how would the final file look like - with everything together please?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't there for a while. See Edited text. I have added the final file. I hope it will help. I would suggest to see my reference link to jquery.com for better understanding.